Randomly sample points for each feature within a feature collection in Google Earth Engine
I am using Google Earth Engine to randomly sample points within each feature (multi-polygon) within a feature collection. However, I cannot figure out how to do it. For now, I only manage to randomly sample points for the whole feature collection. But what I need is 1000 randomly sampled points within each feature (0-11).
This is the code I'm using so far:
var points= ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(polygons, 1000);
How can I solve this?
"polygons" is the feature collection with the structure you see in the picture.


You can do this by mapping over your collection and creating random points for each feature:
// For each polygon...
var points = polygons.map(function(ft) {
  // Sample points within the polygon
  return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(ft.geometry(), 1000);
}).flatten();

The map returns a nested feature collection of feature collections, so using flatten converts that into a flat collection of features.
If you want to store metadata about the polygon each point was sampled from in its properties, you can use map again to set a property based on the polygon's system:index (for example):
// For each polygon...
var points = polygons.map(function(ft) {
  // Get the ID of the polygon
  var polygon_id = ft.get("system:index");
  
  // Sample points within the polygon
  return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(ft.geometry(), 1000)
    // Set a "polygon_id" property for each point
    .map(function(pt) {return pt.set("polygon_id", polygon_id)});
}).flatten();


That's great, it works! Thank you.
Do you know how I can retain the ID of the polygon a point belongs to, in the final output? So that I know that points 1 belongs to polygon 14 for example.

Sure! I edited my answer to include that.

Thank you Aaron Zuspan for your help!
